# how to set Date Time PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have only this field of `php` statment, and the output of this field is: `August 11 2016` but how can I make this `11 08 2016` ?

```
<?php the_time(get_option( 'date_format' )); ?>
```

Comment: are we talking about [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time)? `the_time('d m Y')` will do it, or you shoud find date_format option and adjust it's value

Comment: yes this was what I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you referring to the WordPress function `the_time()` found here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time

If so, inside the parenthesis you can specify the format as below:

```
<?php the_time('d m Y'); ?>
```

If you would like a list of the formatting options for PHP dates check the below manual page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple solution:

```
echo date('d m Y', strtotime("August 11 2016"));
```

- First convert your string date into a `Unix time-stamp` using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
- Then convert it to the date format of your choice

[<kbd>**Check Demo Here**</kbd>](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%5Cn%20echo%20date('d%20m%20Y',%20strtotime(%22August%2011%202016%22));%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)

Answer (score 2):

### Update

[the_time()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) method of wordpress accepts argument of the format you want to print the time. So update the code like this to print it in desired format.

```
<?php the_time('d m Y'); ?>
```

---

You can use [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to create the **DateTime** object from string according to the format, and then use [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method to print it in desired format.

Your code should look something like this,

```
<?php
$date_string= "August 11 2016";
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F d Y',$date_string);
echo $date->format("d m Y");
```

Demo: https://eval.in/621469

Where `F d Y` is the input date format and `d m Y` is the output date format.

> **createFromFormat** returns new DateTime object formatted according to
>   the specified format passed as first argument.

Comment: But this is going to be static I need it to be dynamicly

Comment: What do you want dynamic? Date? In that case store date value in a variable. Check updated answer!

Comment: @AlokPatel - the issue here is the user is using a WordPress defined function which was not mentioned in the question - the_time() is not pure PHP code, hence the confusion.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone oh, in that case OP can pass the argument of desired format.